# Java Recursion Method Parameter Error due to ArrayList

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I have a method like

```
static void conxFinder(ArrayList storage, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> linArray, String linInit, String linFin)
```

I am doing a recursive call to the function

```
conxFinder(storage.add(linArray.get(i).get(0)), linArray.remove(i), linArray.get(i).get(a), linFin);
```

But it gives the error:

```
'conxFinder(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>>, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' in 'tryout' cannot be applied to '(boolean, java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'
```

But when I do it like this (this isn't what I want though)(because recursive call is within a for loop)

```
storage.add(linArray.get(i).get(0));
String linInitial = linArray.get(i).get(a);
linArray.remove(i);
conxFinder(storage, linArray, linInitial, linFin);
```

There are no issues. How can I resolve my problem? How can I get this below to work:

```
conxFinder(storage.add(linArray.get(i).get(0)), linArray.remove(i), linArray.get(i).get(a), linFin);
```

Comment: `List#add` returns a boolean indicating whether the collection was modified. It does not return the original collection and is not "chainable".

Comment: How can I resolve the issue? Is there anything else I can use? And how about the remove part? It gives an error as well.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. It seems you understand the error and identified the solution. Are you looking for a magic flag that allows your compiler to understand invalid code?

Comment: And I don't see what this has to do with recursion.

Comment: The original function is 'static void conxFinder(ArrayList storage, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> linArray, String linInit, String linFin)'

Comment: I need a recursive call like 'conxFinder(storage.add(linArray.get(i).get(0)), linArray.remove(i), linArray.get(i).get(a), linFin);'

Comment: where I change the parameters. (I need to add a String element to List Storage, and remove an element from List linArray) How can I do this? I hope it's clear.

Comment: And what is wrong with the solution you already got?

Comment: Well I have no solution. The recursive call is within a for loop (I guess I'll edit it) and so it is necessary that the parameters don't change except withinthe method itself.

Answer (score 0):

The call

```
conxFinder(storage.add(linArray.get(i).get(0)), linArray.remove(i), linArray.get(i).get(a), linFin);
```

doesn't work because:

- `storage.add(linArray.get(i).get(0))` returns a boolean, but the first parameter of `conxFinder` is an `ArrayList` (it must be `storage`)
- `linArray.remove(i)` returns a `ArrayList<String>` (the element at position `i`), but the second parameter of `conxFinder` is a `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` (it must be `linArray`)

You could try to work around those problems by writing helper methods:

```
private static ArrayList<String> add(ArrayList<String> storage, String value) {
    storage.add(value);
    return storage;
}

private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> remove(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> linArray, int i) {
    linArray.remove(i);
    return linArray;
}
```

And then the recursive call could be done as

```
conxFinder(add(storage, linArray.get(i).get(0)), remove(linArray, i), linArray.get(i).get(a), linFin);
```

**But** this has one problem left: the evaluation order for method parameters is strictly left to right.

And this means that `linArray.remove(i)` (or `remove(linArray, i)`) is evaluated **before** `linArray.get(i).get(a)` and therefore `linArray.get(i).get(a)` loads the wrong value from `linArray`.

---

Therefore, whether you like it or not, the only solution is

```
storage.add(linArray.get(i).get(0));
String linInitial = linArray.get(i).get(a);
linArray.remove(i);
conxFinder(storage, linArray, linInitial, linFin);
```

---

From your comment it seems that you want to do

```
for (int p = 0; p < linArray.get(i).size(); p++) { 
    int a = ((j+p) % (linArray.get(i).size())); 
    if (j != a && a != 0 && linArray.size() != 0 ) { 
        storage.add(linArray.get(i).get(0)); 
        String linInitial = linArray.get(i).get(a); 
        linArray.remove(i); 
        conxFinder(storage, linArray, linInitial, linFin);
    }
}
```

And somehow not change `storage` and `linArray` within the `for` loop. But rewriting those inner four lines with the helper methods into (note that I changed the order of the second and third parameter)

```
for (int p = 0; p < linArray.get(i).size(); p++) { 
    int a = (j+p) % linArray.get(i).size(); 
    if (j != a && a != 0 && linArray.size() != 0 ) { 
        conxFinder(add(storage, linArray.get(i).get(0)), linArray.get(i).get(a), remove(linArray, i), linFin);        }
}
```

doesn't change the fact that `storage` and `linArray` **are** changed within the `for` loop - the change might be more hidden within those helper methods, but they are still changed.

If you want the unchanged values, you must preserve them yourself (Java will not do it for you):

```
for (int p = 0; p < linArray.get(i).size(); p++) { 
    int a = (j+p) % linArray.get(i).size(); 
    if (j != a && a != 0 && linArray.size() != 0 ) {
        ArrayList<String> nStorage = new ArrayList<>(storage);
        nStorage.add(linArray.get(i).get(0)); 
        String linInitial = linArray.get(i).get(a); 
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> nLinArray = new ArrayList<>(linArray);
        nLinArray.remove(i); 
        conxFinder(nStorage, nLinArray, linInitial, linFin);
    }
}
```

Only this will preserve `storage` and `linArray`.

Comment: The thing is the recursive call is within a for loop. So I shouldn't change the values except within the function. If there is another way, I'd like to hear. But the solution you've given looks alright enough, if Java reads the method from left to right, I can change linArray.get(i).get(a) to the left (it's possible for me).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with _shouldn't change the values except within the function_. Both variants change `storage` and `linArray` before the function call (because effectively `storage` and `linArray` are only references to objects, not the objects themselves) and that change persists during the recursive call and beyond. In Java calling a function never copies objects.

Comment: for (int p=0; p<linArray.get(i).size(); p++) {
      int a = ((j+p)%(linArray.get(i).size()));
      if (j!=a && a!=0 && linArray.size() != 0 ) {            
           storage.add(linArray.get(i).get(0));
           String linInitial = linArray.get(i).get(a);
           linArray.remove(i);
           conxFinder(storage, linArray, linInitial, linFin);

Comment: My code was like this initially (sorry for horrid formatting) so within a for loop. I wanted to have the same values for every iteration in the loop, but if it's outside the function call it won't have that.